# FileSystemException: Cannot copy file ' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to copy a sqflite database file from this path (getDatabasesPath()) to external storage,but I got this exception:

```
 FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/storage/emulated/0/databaseBackup', path = '/data/user/0/com.example.project/databases/roznamcha.db' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)
```

My code:

```
  Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      var result = await permission.request();
      if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<bool> createDirectory() async {
    Directory directory;
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
          directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
          String newPath = "";
          print(directory);
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
          for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
            String folder = paths[x];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/" + folder;
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          newPath = newPath + "/databaseBackup";
          directory = Directory(newPath);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.photos)) {
          directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        await directory.create(recursive: true);
      }
      if (await directory.exists()) {
        final pathdb = await getDatabasesPath();
        // join database name and database path
        final path = join(pathdb, 'roznamcha.db');
        print('path ra print ko: $path');
        File f = File(path);
        var cop = await f.copy(directory.path);
        print(directory.path);
        print('copy file $cop');
      }
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I added permission_handler package and also permission configuration to AndroidManiFaes.xml but I still get this error.

Comment: You cannot copy a file to a `directory` path, you shold append the file name to that, try using join (`join(directory.path, roznamcha.db)`) and using that path

Comment: it dos not work it still getting the same error @Mattia

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting an error is that the app attempts to right in the directory path. You can explore other directory paths that you can use and see if it fits your use case. Try writing with `getTemporaryDirectory()` and other paths. Check this [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/path_provider-library.html) for more details.